# ArrayList Index Out Of Bound exception in android custom list view adapter

Tags: java, android

This is my below code , where my list looks like

```
position 1  |  image1      image2      image3
            ----------------------------------------
position 2  |  image1      image2      image3
```

I mean dynamically adding my images according to number of items in list for eg if my list has 21 items , then mylist populate 3 images in each position and totally 7 position gets created. My code is working fine

```
 public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static final String TAG = "Book-shelf";
private Activity activity;
private int totalBooks = 0;
private int bookItem = 0;
private int numberOfBookRows = 0;
private int extraBooks = 0;
int layoutId;
private int bookImage;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public ListViewAdapter(Activity a, int listRow,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fileList) {
    super();

    activity = a;
    dataList = fileList;
    layoutId = listRow;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dataList.size();
}
```

**The modified one is for the above getCountmethod**

```
   @Override
public Object getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return numberOfBookRows;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dataList.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public void calculateRowsAndColms() {
    totalBooks = 0;
    bookItem = 0;
    numberOfBookRows = 0;
    extraBooks = 0;

    totalBooks = dataList.size();
    bookItem = 3;// TODO: make it dynamic
    if (totalBooks < bookItem && totalBooks > 0) {
        numberOfBookRows = 1;
    } else {
        numberOfBookRows = (totalBooks / bookItem);
        extraBooks = (totalBooks % bookItem);
        if (extraBooks != 0)
            numberOfBookRows++;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, " Total books:" + totalBooks);
    Log.d(TAG, " Number of books to be displayed:" + bookItem);
    Log.d(TAG, " Number of rows occupying the books:" + numberOfBookRows);
    Log.d(TAG, " Number of extra books(odd count):" + extraBooks);
}
```

This is my View code of arrayadapter

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;
    Log.d("View", "view" + v);
    calculateRowsAndColms();
    bookImage = R.drawable.book1;
    Log.d("Datalist","size="+dataList.size());
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null, false);

        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image3);

        TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        holder.imgList.add(image1);
        holder.imgList.add(image2);
        holder.imgList.add(image3);

        holder.textList.add(t1);
        holder.textList.add(t2);
        holder.textList.add(t3);

        v.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    int k;

 if ((position == numberOfBookRows - 1) && extraBooks != 0) {


                    for (int i = 0; i < extraBooks; i++) {
                        Log.d("inside if", "position" + position);
                        Log.d("inside if", "numberofbookrows" + numberOfBookRows);
                        int k = (position * bookItem) + i;
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setBackgroundResource(bookImage);
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setOnClickListener(
                                new OnBookClickListner());
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setId(k);
                        holder.textList.get(i).setText(dataList.get(k).get("pdf"));
                        Log.d("if k value","k="+k+"value="+dataList.get(k).get("pdf"));

                    }

                } else if((position <= numberOfBookRows - 1) && totalBooks<bookItem)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++) {

                        Log.d("inside else", "position" + position);
                        Log.d("inside else", "numberofbookrows" + numberOfBookRows);
                        int k = (position * bookItem) + i;
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setBackgroundResource(bookImage);
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setOnClickListener(
                                new OnBookClickListner());
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setId(k);
                        holder.textList.get(i).setText(dataList.get(k).get("pdf"));
                        Log.d("2nd if k value","k="+k+"value="+dataList.get(k).get("pdf"));

                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bookItem; i++) {
                        int k = (position * bookItem) + i;
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setBackgroundResource(bookImage);
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setOnClickListener(
                                new OnBookClickListner());
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.imgList.get(i).setId(k);
                        holder.textList.get(i).setText(dataList.get(k).get("pdf"));
                        Log.d("3rd if k value","k="+k+"value="+dataList.get(k).get("pdf"));

                    }

                }

return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    ArrayList<ImageView> imgList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    ArrayList<TextView> textList = new ArrayList<TextView>();

    // ImageView image1, image2 ,image3;
}

public class OnBookClickListner implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, " ITEM SELECTED IN LIST VIEW:" + v.getId());
        /*
         * Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
         * MainActivity.class); startActivity(intent);
         */
    }

}

}
```

Now When i run this code , im getting my expected output, but when i try to scroll the list, the app get close and i get fatal exception

```
    07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 21, size is 20
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.example.samplebookshelfdesign.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:151)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2161)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:639)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4970)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3126)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3400)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7384)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2203)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1938)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
07-22 03:57:26.501: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
```

Comment: Which line of code is ListViewAdapter.java:151?

Comment: Which line is `ListViewAdapter.java:151`?

Comment: Line under else part holder.textList.get(j).setText(dataList.get(k).get("pdf"));

Comment: I think you need to log and check the index `k`, and the problem is at `dataList.get(k)`.

Comment: i have already logged, this is the output                                                                                 07-22 04:43:36.641: D/View(1518): viewnull
    07-22 04:43:36.811: D/Book-shelf(1518):  Total books:20
    07-22 04:43:36.811: D/Book-shelf(1518):  Number of books to be displayed:3
    07-22 04:43:36.821: D/Book-shelf(1518):  Number of rows occupying the books:7
 
    07-22 04:43:36.831: D/Datalist(1518): size=20
    07-22 04:43:37.041: D/K data(1518): k=0text =file1
    07-22 04:43:37.041: D/K data(1518): k=1text =file2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your if/else condition. You don't handle the case where `position` exceeds the number of rows.

```
if ((position == numberOfBookRows - 1) && extraBooks != 0) {
  // ...
} else {
  // This will also get executed if position > numberOfBooksRows -1
}
```

You probably should add an additional guard:

```
if ((position == numberOfBookRows - 1) && extraBooks != 0) {
  // ...
} else if (position < numberOfBookRows - 1) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes what you said is correct , but in my case i did small mistake, in getItem() method iam returning the dataList.size() , so my position in view goes with respect to datalist size, but i want to move it according to my numberOfBookRows so that i have list position according to book rows.

Comment: I have updated my above code, Now there is no problem of index out of bound exception . since i was using wrong position to identify in view. But now what happening is the no of images getting displayed wrongly, i mean if i have 20 files then 20 images should display with its name, but fr me it displays 21 images with name from with in this 20 file names. on of file name from this 20 gets repeated oly in this 21st position, i have edited the screen shot fr the same

Comment: please help me i have edited my code @Robby Cornelissen

Comment: Don't know what the actual issue is, but: 1) the conditions in your `else if` block look weird, and 2) why do you need 3 blocks (`if ... else if ... else ...`)?